# Как добавить в список информацию из другого скрипта?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как добавить в список информацию из другого скрипта?
Извиняюсь если вопрос глупый но я не нашел в интернете ответа.
Но как запустить new MyInfo("name1") Внутри другого скрипта

File1Scr

```
public class MyInfo
{
    string Name;
    
    public MyInfo(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    
}



// Работает
list.Add(new MyInfo("name1"));
```

File2Scr

```
File1Scr MyInfo;


// Не работает
list.Add(new MyInfo("name1"));
```

Unity мне пишет

> 'MyInfo' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Comment: Приведите нормальный код. Тот, что в вопросе не может работать. Хотя бы из за конструктора Card(string) в классе MyInfo.

Comment: Судя по ошибке, у вас конструктор в классе `MyInfo` либо отсутствует, либо у него аргументов больше одного. Приложите код из вашего проекта. Полностью классы, с которыми такая проблема возникла.

Comment: в "File2Scr" под "MyInfo" понимается экземпляр класса "File1Scr" -> вы сами объявили поле типа File1Scr с именем MyInfo. Поэтому "new MyInfo("name1")" никак не связано с классом MyInfo, а связано с классом File1Scr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давай вкратце, что такое скрипт на обьекте? Правильно - это компонент, а как мы помним мы можем манипулировать компонентами. Создайте публичную переменную типа этого компонента(см.пример) и в юнити перетащите его на место. Дальше вы можете взаимодействовать с скриптом как захочете

```
public MyScript player;
player.speed = 50;
```

Надеюсь понятно разьеснил